# Client side grouping in a Grid with very large number of rows

Tags: javascript, grouping, grid-layout, summary

We have an requirement in which we have a large number of data coming from server, say around `1.5 million` of rows with around 10 columns. Its a very bad idea to load all the data at client side. But, there is a requirement of `Grouping with Summaries`. For example: Suppose there are 4 columns `A, B, C, D` We need to find `Sum` of values in column `B` group by column `A`.

The levels of grouping can be greater than 2. Like group by Column A, then group by B. Here is an example of such a Grid [Ignite UI Grid Grouping Example](http://www.igniteui.com/grid/grouping). This is [an another example](http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-grouping)  in which 3 levels of grouping is there, with summary. (We are not using SlickGrid because it has very limited grid functionalities)

**My question is**:

As it is not a good idea to take million of rows to display, how can we show group based summaries in a grid like `igGrid` Showing summary can be important always. What can be standard approach for it?

Thanks

Comment: You can always retrieve a sensible amount of rows from the database first, with all the fields needed, to then load the next batch by adding a "Load more" option, or a pagination, and so on. In short: use a Load More option or pagination as a good practice to load big amounts of data.

Comment: @Teknotica but, how this will give me summary if i will do grouping with current amount of data?